# Does anyone understand what "templed terraces" could mean?

Tags: expressions

The full sentence is: "In the **templed terraces** of Zar lie all the dreams of beauty and thoughts of beauty that come to men once and are forgotten;" it's an excerpt from an adventure from Call of Cthulhu's Horror on the Orient Express Book, and I find it hard to grasp its meaning...

Comment: Terraces with temples on them.

Comment: Thanks, not used to that image, being in Brazil, tried google to no luck, but now that you both explained it, I got the idea.

Comment: Apparently this is not Brazil, but it's close: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Palenque_ruins_web.jpg

Comment: Haha, thanks, yeah, that's Mexico. But I got the idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suggests that Zar is in hilly country that has been terraced, and many temples have been built on those terraces.

The phrase **templed terraces** is used poetically, followed as it is by ideas of beauty and thoughts and dreams.